# Getting org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerNotificationException on building war using gradle & spring boot

Tags: spring, gradle, spring-boot, out-of-memory, war

While doing a gradle build of war using spring boot I am getting the
    below error. On commenting spring boot everything works as expected.
 My build.gradle looks as below:

```
apply plugin: 'war'

apply plugin: 'java'

apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
```

and few compile dependencies for the project specific jars

Exception is:

```
org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerNotificationException: Failed to notify dependency resolution listener.
       at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:55)
       at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:79)
       at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:30)
       at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.beforeResolve(Unknown Source)
       at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.performPreResolveActions(DefaultConfiguration.java:388)
       at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveGraphIfRequired(DefaultConfiguration.java:369)
       at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveNow(DefaultConfiguration.java:346)
       at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.getBuildDependencies(DefaultConfiguration.java:414)
       at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration_Decorated.getBuildDependencies(Unknown Source)
       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext$TaskGraphImpl.getNodeValues(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:92)
       at org.gradle.internal.graph.CachingDirectedGraphWalker$GraphWithEmpyEdges.getNodeValues(CachingDirectedGraphWalker.java:202)
       at org.gradle.internal.graph.CachingDirectedGraphWalker.doSearch(CachingDirectedGraphWalker.java:112)
       at org.gradle.internal.graph.CachingDirectedGraphWalker.findValues(CachingDirectedGraphWalker.java:64)
       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.doResolve(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:76)
       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.resolve(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:65)
       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.getDependencies(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:55)
       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.addToTaskGraph(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:139)
       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.addTasks(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:98)
       at org.gradle.execution.TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.configure(TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.java:47)
       at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:48)
       at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:25)
       at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:54)
       at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.configure(DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.java:44)
       at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:48)
       at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:25)
       at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:54)
       at org.gradle.execution.ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.configure(ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.java:47)
       at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:48)
       at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.select(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:36)
       at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:143)
       at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:52)
       at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:140)
       at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
       at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:99)
       at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
       at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
       at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:82)
       at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:94)
       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
       at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
       at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
       at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
       at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
       at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:45)
       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:52)
       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
       at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:40)
       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:66)
       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
aused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
       at io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.exclusions.DependencyGraph$_create_closure1.doCall(DependencyGraph.groovy:38)
       at io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.exclusions.DependencyGraph.doVisit(DependencyGraph.groovy:59)
       at io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.exclusions.DependencyGraph.doVisit(DependencyGraph.groovy:65)
       at io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.exclusions.DependencyGraph.doVisit(DependencyGraph.groovy:65)


BUILD FAILED
```

Please let me know how to resolve the same.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think the cause of the problem lies in the "few compile dependencies for the project specific jars". Can you provide a complete example that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Actually war is including dependencies in this format. 

Subproject A

Subproject B

Common modules - which will be included in every war 

A and B are built parallel. But if I disable the parallel build in gradle also, it has no effect.
If we monitor the gradle process in task manager, we can see a huge spike in memory of gradle process as soon as I enable spring boot. Any advice would be greatly appreciated..

Comment: My advice is to provide a complete example that reproduces the problem. Something's going wrong in the dependency management plugin that Spring Boot uses but I can't tell what.

Comment: I cant provide complete example, as its a proprietary code. However, attaching build.gradle and debug logs. Please let me know if you be able to help me with these.                             http://www.filedropper.com/buildgradle
http://www.filedropper.com/debuglogs

Comment: Just wondering if its a issue of adding spring dependencies of different version other than the one for spring boot. Say spring boot version I am using is 1.3.5.RELEASE. But in our projects we have mentioned the spring dependencies as 4.0.1. So will this conflict with the dependency management of spring boot? We want to run the project both with spring boot and normal deployment